# Trouble connecting objects in .kv file to python class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning Kivy and having trouble connecting my objects declared in the .kv file to the python class in order to update their properties. No matter which way I try I get this error:

```
self.kbCompressionLabel.text = 'Hello World'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The app loads all the kivy files fine, and only breaks when I try to update from the Class.

I've dumbed down the current code to the minimum to illustrate how it is setup. Any help is much appreciated.

Main app entry

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

Builder.load_file('appscreenmanager.kv')
Builder.load_file('compressorscreen.kv')
Builder.load_file('slidersview.kv')

class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class AppManager(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppScreenManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AppManager().run()
```

Dumed down appscreenmanager.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<AppScreenManager>:
    CompressorScreen:
    ...
```

compressorscreen.kv

```
<CompressorScreen>:
    name: 'compressor'
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        cols: 1
    SlidersView:
    ...
```

This is where the issue is happening: simplified slidersview.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import slidersview slidersview

<slidersView>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 2
    id: sliders
    kbCompressionLabel: kbCompressionLabel

    Label:
        id: kbCompressionLabel
        text: 'test'
```

slidersview.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class SlidersView(GridLayout):
    # properties
    sliders = ObjectProperty(None)
    kbCompressionLabel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kbCompressionLabel.text = 'Hello World'
        super(SlidersView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I had to add a delay into the init function then things worked. However, this feels pretty wonky to me. Is this the expected behavior?

Updated slidersview.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class SlidersView(GridLayout):
    # properties
    kbCompressionLabel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SlidersView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        @mainthread
        def delayed():
            self.kbCompressionLabel.text = 'Hello World'
        delayed()
```

Answer (score 1):

The KV definitions are applied only when you call `__init__` of the base classes...
reverse the order and you'll be fine...

```
class SlidersView(GridLayout):
    # properties
    sliders = ObjectProperty(None)
    kbCompressionLabel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(SlidersView, self).__init__(**kwargs) #first!
        self.kbCompressionLabel.text = 'Hello World' #2nd!
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and get the same results. Which makes me think the issue is elsewhere in my setup

Comment: After more troubleshooting I can only not access my widgets within the __init__ method. It's as if they aren't being created yet. Any ideas why that might be?